# C# DKIMKeySigner Can't open attachments

Tags: c#, mailer, dkim

I'm sending mails to users with attachments. 
Mails that aren't signed, get a .pdf file (around 64kb) and are working perfectly fine.

However, when I sign them for other users, the PDF file becomes around 64 **B** and can't be opened.

I'm not doing anything with the attachments while signing, however.. so this is very odd.

My code for signing:

```
 email = SpecificMethods.DKIMSign(email);

internal static MailMessage DKIMSign(MailMessage email)
    {
        var privateKey = PrivateKeySigner.Create(@"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
         -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");

        var domainKeySigner = new DomainKeySigner(privateKey, "***.com", "**", new string[] { "mime-version", "date", "subject", "from", "to", "content-type" });
        email.DomainKeySign(domainKeySigner);

        var dkimSigner = new DkimSigner(privateKey, "***.com", "**", new string[] { "mime-version", "date", "subject", "from", "to", "content-type" });
        email.DkimSign(dkimSigner);

        return email;
    }
```

And eventually send it. Nothing special happening there.

Any reason why my attachment would 'break'??

Comment: I would recommend using my [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) and [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) libraries for signing messages with DKIM and sending them via SMTP.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you shall change the library used to sign the messages **or** the class used to send the actual email. I tried a *quick* search for an alternate to `System.Net.SmtpClient` but found none.

You did not specify which DLL package you used, so a Google search teleported me to [this project](https://github.com/dmcgiv/DKIM.Net)

Unfortunately, if you look at the Readme...

---

## Known Issues

As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient generates boundary identifiers randomly and as this code hacks the SmtpClient to retrieve the full email content before sending the code **cannot be used when** sending with SmtpClient and the MailMessage **when the MailMessage has** an alternative view or **an attachment**.

---